# Adding complete disjunctive assumption in Coq

Tags: coq, theorem-proving

In mathematics, we often proceed as follows: "Now let us consider two cases, the number `k` can be `even` or `odd`. For the `even` case, we can say `exists k', 2k' = k`..."

Which expands to the general idea of reasoning about an entire set of objects by disassembling it into several disjunct subsets that can be used to reconstruct the original set.

How is this reasoning principle captured in coq considering we do not always have an assumption that is one of the subsets we want to deconstruct into?

Consider the follow example for demonstration:

`forall n, Nat.Even n => P n.`

Here we can naturally do `inversion` on `Nat.Even n` to get `n = 2*x` (and an automatically-false eliminated assumption that `n = 2*x + 1`). However, suppose we have the following:

`forall n, P n`

How can I state: "let us consider `even n`s and `odd n`s". Do I need to first show that we have decidable `forall n : nat, even n \/ odd n`? That is, introduce a new (local or global) lemma listing all the required subsets? What are the best practices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, to reason about a splitting of a class of objects in Coq you need to show an algorithm splitting them, unless you want to reason classically (there is nothing wrong with that).

IMO, a key point is getting such decidability hypotheses "for free". For instance, you could implement `odd : nat -> bool` as a boolean function, as it is done in some libraries, then you get the splitting for free.

[edit]
You can use some slightly more convenient techniques for pattern matching, by enconding the pertinent cases as inductives:

```
Require Import PeanoNat Nat Bool.

CoInductive parity_spec (n : nat) : Type :=
| parity_spec_odd : odd  n = true -> parity_spec n
| parity_spec_even: even n = true -> parity_spec n
.

Lemma parityP n : parity_spec n.
Proof.
case (even n) eqn:H; [now right|left].
now rewrite <- Nat.negb_even, H.
Qed.

Lemma test n : even n = true \/ odd n = true.
Proof. now case (parityP n); auto. Qed.
```

Comment: Yes, so with the standard library's `Nat.odd` for this, just do `destruct (Nat.odd n) eqn:Hodd.`  That puts `Hodd: Nat.odd n = true` in one goal context and `Hodd : Nat.odd n = false` in another. (If you don't put the `eqn:Hname`, Coq forgets the association between `odd n` and the case its considering.)

Comment: Is there any reason why you use a `CoInductive` here ?